# switching to pdf view with Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: lyx, viewers

I just installed Lyx 2.1 on my computer for the first time.
I wanted to create my first trial pdf but switching to viewing mode is for some reason not working with the Acrobat Reader DC. I tried many options found on the web but I am afraid my little knowledge is not sufficing to make it work.

I would really appreciate a detailed answer :)

Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9512

Comment: Also, you might want to give SumatraPDF a try. I've heard good things about it from Windows users.

Comment: Adobe crobat locks .pdf files, so that you have to close it before recompiling. SumatraPDF doesn't lock files.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the file pdfview.exe on your PC with this one:
http://ftp.lyx.de/LyX%202.1.3/pdfview.exe

Usually it is located in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\LyX 2.1\bin`